# Problems with output plot of PCA+environmental factors (with envfit) with vegan

Tags: r, plot, pca, vegan

I have a dataset from 6 samples with lots of species (12k) and some environmental factors (7 factors). I am trying to do a PCA ordination of the species and then add the environmental factors to the analysis and to the plot using `vegan` package. What I do is the following:

```
>pca.spec <- rda(spec) 
>groups <- factor(rownames(spec)) 
>plot(pca.spec) 
>text(pca.spec, labels=groups)
```

And then

```
> env_fact <- read.csv("env_fact.csv") 
> ef <- envfit(pca.spec, env_fact, permu=999)
> plot(ef)
```

The output is the following:

```
***VECTORS

                       PC1      PC2     r2 Pr(>r)
pH                -0.55984 -0.82860 0.1914 0.7556
NH4                0.00204  1.00000 0.3108 0.5319
NO2               -0.51192  0.85904 0.5042 0.3000
NO3               -0.86533  0.50121 0.0857 0.9361
Total.inorganic.N -0.18298  0.98312 0.2164 0.6500
X..N.total        -0.49702  0.86774 0.2600 0.4806
X..C.total        -0.47205  0.88157 0.2618 0.4931
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 720

***FACTORS:

Centroids:
           PC1     PC2
SSPIA0 -2.0704  3.2416
SSPIA1 -1.8165 -4.1363
SSPIA2 -1.0806 -7.0426
SSPIA3  9.2544  0.7544
SSPIA4 -2.1292  3.6535
SSPIA5 -2.1578  3.5293

Goodness of fit:
   r2 Pr(>r)
SS  1      1
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 720
```

And a plot with the 'Centroids' represented in the same position as the samples itself (duplicated information) and the arrows without the name of the factor they represent in a position that allows to identify them (they seems to appear too far from the end of the arrow).

[image]

How can I move the names closer to their corresponding arrows? How can I remove 'centroids' ('factors') from the plot?

I'm also not sure whether I carried out the analysis correctly.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: note that the distance from the arrow points is slightly impacted by the size of the plotting window. So if you generated the plot in a small window and then enlarged it, the spacing between lablels and arrows will seem wide. Set the plotting window to the desired size and then rerun the plotting code. That should help